# Stripe: 3D-Secure on the Android SDK

Tags: android, stripe-payments, payment, 3d-secure

On my `Android` project, I have been given the task of implementing `3D-Secure` support using `Stripe`. I see that the `SDK` so far doesn’t have a facility to add a `“3d_secure”` object to the card parameters. The `iOS SDK` however, has a provision to do this on their native `Card` object. Is there a similar facility for the `Android SDK` in the works? Or is the only way I can go about this somehow creating a wrapper of my own for it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://support.stripe.com/questions/does-stripe-support-3d-secure-verified-by-visa-mastercard-securecode

Comment: Thanks @MatthewArkin. But I already came across that page. But I know that the iOS team has used a version of the Stripe SDK that has a provision to supply 3d-secure parameters along with their card object. I've asked this question only after much research. :)

Comment: Then it sounds like you have access to some private beta and you should talk to Stripe support about it

Comment: @MatthewArkin. Yes, I assumed so. I've done just that. Hopefully I'll get a reply soon.

Comment: @RameezHussain any response from Stripe about 3D?

Comment: @JonatanLundqvistMedén. Yes. They're working on it. It's in beta and they're not sure when it will be out. So they've asked me to either fork their project or send in my own POST request manually.

Comment: @RameezHussain I using their 3D Secure beta now hade have been doing so for the last month and it works good.